# networkx ego_graph apply to geopandas series speed-up

Tags: networkx, geopandas, osmnx

Having `GeoSeries` of around 100000 locations, I have a working code for calculating `Polygons`  of walking  accessibility from each location as a center.

The code does calculations over `networkx` graph, obtained from `OpenStreeMaps` via `osmnx` by `apply` to  `GeoDataFrame`.

I am trying to speed up calculation, as that is incredibly slow.

`G` - is a `networkx` graph

```
# create graph walking_time edge property

walking_speed = 4.5 #km/h
walking_speed_m_minute = walking_speed * 1000 / 60 #km/h to m/min
for u, v, k, data in G.edges(data=True, keys=True):
    data['walking_time'] = data['length'] / walking_speed_m_minute
```

This is the func I `apply` to `GeoDataFrame`:

```
def calculate_time_accessibility_polygon(row, trip_time):
    # location x,y
    y = row['latitude']
    x = row['longitude']
    # find nearest node on the graph
    center_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (y, x))
    subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G, center_node, radius=trip_time, 
distance='time')
    node_points = [Point((data['x'], data['y'])) for node, data in 
subgraph.nodes(data=True)]
    bounding_poly = gpd.GeoSeries(node_points).unary_union.convex_hull
    return(bounding_poly)
```

I apply with the following line of code:

```
gdf.apply(calculate_time_accessibility_polygon, args=(15,), axis=1))
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: I am curious if someone will find a way how to make it faster. `ego_graph` is taking the majority of the time, it you find a way how to speed up this part, whole script will speed up significantly. However, as someone who tried doing the same before, I am not very optimistic about it, there is a lot of computation behind needed to generate ego_graph.